# Why the following program does not end on IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have the following python program using threads. I am unable to understand why it does not terminate after execution. Suggest possible reasons and how to overcome this problem. Here is the code -

```
import time
from threading import *

lock1 = Lock()
def func(string):
    for i in range(5):
        lock1.acquire()

        print(string)
        lock1.release()
        time.sleep(0.1)

t1 = Thread(target = func, args = ('Hello from t1',))
t2 = Thread(target = func, args = ('Hello from t2',))


t1.start()
t2.start()
print(t1.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple, it is not ending because it is not making an exit from main thread. Moreover, it may run on IDLE but will not run on shell.